# Centering a value both vertically and horizontally MUI

Tags: material-ui

Following the MUI documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/ I thought all I needed to center something both vertically and horizontally was to include `justifyContent='center' alignItems='center`, but this only centers it horizontally and not vertically. I'm just trying to align it both horizontally and vertically in the paper component.

Any help would be appreciated:

```
               <Paper
                    elevation={2}
                    sx={{
                        minWidth: '30%%',
                        height: '100%',
                    }}
                >
                    <Box
                        display='flex'
                        justifyContent='center'
                        alignItems='center'
                    >
                        <Typography>0</Typography>
                    </Box>
                </Paper>
```

[image: Trying to center the 0]
[image: MUI Docs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set dimensions on the Box component in order for the flex attributes to take effect. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-glade-m9k6l5

Comment: Dang, I thought the box inherited the dimensions from the paper. Thank you for your help!